# for loop not looping, returns only initial value

Tags: solidity

Trying to get it to subtract down from `i` by 4's and return the final results (answer is either: 1, 2, 3 or 4)

```
for(uint i = 1000; i >= 1; i-=4)    { 

            return(i);  

        }
```

but when I `return(i);` or `return i;` i get the initial value of `i` (in this case 1000) not the subtracted value.

Any explanations or help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)? (`%`) This is the same as remainder. Thus 1000 % 4 = 0 because 4 divides 1000 perfectly. If you want results between 1-4, you can have a check for 0 and turn it into 4.

Comment: im not dividing, im subtracting. here is a simpler example: 10 - 4 = 6, 6 - 4 = 2 -- the result (i) should be "2"

Comment: Repeated subtraction is equal to division. It appears to me you are looking for the remainder of 10/4. That is written as `10 % 4` which is equal to 2. You can try yourself in google search.

Answer (score 2):

It exits/breaks from the loop on the first iteration of `return`.

It sounds like you're expecting it to return multiple times but only one response is possible.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment below, a loop isn't the solution. You want a modulo (remainder) and this can be done in one step.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Modulo {

    function getMod4(uint number) public pure returns(uint modulo) {
        return number % 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want the "last" result returned, ie, when it cant subtract 4 anymore and get a number greater than 1. for example, lets start with 10. so 10 - 4 = 6, then 6 - 4 = 2 and since we cant subtract 4 and get a number greater than 1, 2 would be our answer and the desired return for i.

Comment: Have a look at the gist posted above. It works perfectly in Remix so you can try it out. Input `10` returns `2`. The answer, though, is 0,1,2 or 3.

Comment: You can see how @Shawn catches the 0 case and just swaps it for a 4 to strictly match the results you expect.

Answer (score 2):

More specifically, as soon as you call `return`, the whole function which contains this loop will stop and return whatever you passed in the return statement. Think of `return` as a hard stop to any function execution.

In this case, as soon as `return(i)` runs the first time, the loop will stop, which is why you are getting back `1000`, which is the value you started with.

If you want to return the last value `i` you need to do something like this:

```
function remainder() public pure returns(uint) {
  uint r;
  for(uint i = 1000; i >= 1; i-=4) { 
    r = i;  
  }

  return r;
}
```

But this is super inefficient and will waste a bunch of gas (if called within another function). You should be using the modulus operator for this kind of math. In solidity, the modulus operator is represented by `%`.

Here is an example of a function which does what I think you want:

```
function remainderBetter(uint i) public pure returns(uint){
    uint r = i % 4;
    if (r == 0) {
        return 4;
    }

    return r;
}
```